# PayPal SDK Integration for membership website

Tags: paypal

So I'm building a membership website. The principle is simple in that you sign up for a recurring membership, then you are allowed to register, and the server will be notified of all payments or non-payments so it can keep the membership active or disable it for non-payment.

So two questions, and this is pretty broad since I'm just looking for the right place to start.

1. Does this require full PayPal SDK integration (I'm using CakePHP) or is it possible to use the simpler Premade solutions - I guess my question here is, is the only way for PayPal to contact my server when a member pays through full integration?
2. Is it possible to set this up completely on a local host? I'm building the website on my localhost of course it occurs to me that I don't have it connected to the internet for PayPal to communicate with it directly. Are there work arounds for this?

Really just looking for anyone experienced with this type of E-Commerce to chime in. I'm very experienced with PHP so I'm really just looking for a place to start.